# apache .htaccess to nginx rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I need to change from apache to Nginx but the `.htaccess` doesn' work on the Nginx server.

I got following in my Apache `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# always run through the indexfile
RewriteRule .$ index.php

# don't let people peek into directories without an index file
Options -Indexes
```

When I put a `.htaccess` on the Nginx server, the file gets deleted by the server.
In what kind of file do I have to put the `.htaccess` data (name and suffix please) and how should it be rewritten for Nginx and where do I put the file?

I want all subdirectory files to go through my `index.php` file so I can include specific files from my `index.php` file ...

I have tried something like:

```
# nginx configuration

autoindex off;

location / {
    rewrite .$ /index.php;
}
```

but it doesn't work. The directory looks something like:

```
── root
    ├── folder1
    │   └── folder2
    │       └── file.php
    └── index.php
```

so if I ask for `root/folder1/folder2/file.php` I want the server to load the `root/index.php` as I still have the server url request,
I can include the `root/folder1/folder2/file.php` from my `index.php`

It all works on my apache install, but not on the Nginx server.
Please help me.

#

EDIT:
Turns out the `nginx.conf` file has to be above the root folder and is only accessible if you have access to the folders above the root folder. Like server admin access is necessary.

Comment: Have you found **http://www.anilcetin.com/** yet or **http://winginx.com/en/htaccess**?

Comment: yes and many other sites. I tried put my code in nginx.conf and nginx.conf.txt in the same folder but doesnt work. the nginx server deletes htaccess files automatically. Are the code to go in htaccess file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx doesn't have htaccess files. The code needs to go into the nginx config file. Also, try adding the "last" flag to the rewrite:

```
# nginx configuration

autoindex off;

location / {
    rewrite .* /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: is the file gonna be called nginx.conf and be in the root folder by the index.php?

Comment: @user3434534 No. [See the third paragraph in the beginner's guide which tells you where it is](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html). It's different on different systems.

Comment: if I dont have access to the root directory, is it possible for me to overwrite it with an own nginx.conf file placed in the directory I'm working with?

Comment: @Medda86 No, that's not how nginx works. If you don't have access to the config file, you can't change nginx's behavior.

Comment: ok thanks, I will have to talk to the administration poeple then to set it up for me. Thanks for your explaination.